# Executing python script from Jenkins job giving 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

Below is the snippet from my python script which runs fine from pycharm but if run from Jenkins job's **Execute shell** the job is failing with error saying **SyntaxError: invalid syntax** at `CURRENT_MONTH: Final = "cur_mon"`

```
from typing import Final

CURRENT_MONTH: Final = "cur_mon"
LAST_MONTH: Final = "last_mon"
data_timeline = [CURRENT_MONTH, LAST_MONTH]
```

Command used in Jekins job is `python my_file.py` and `pyhton3 my_file.py`. In both cases it is failing with same error.

Please advise on what could be going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jenkins is running Python `< 3.6`. The variable annotation syntax came in Python `3.6`:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/

Also, `Final` got introduced in Python `3.8` (but missing it would of course raise an `ImportError` instead of a `SyntaxError`):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/